# How to make angular ui bootstrap hoverable popover on multiple buttons?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

While searching on the internet for a solution to allow the ui bootstrap popover to stay open while I hover on the popover itself, I have found an unaccomplished [solution](https://jsbin.com/muwacejuzi/edit?html,js,output).

The problem is that when I hover on a button, all popovers of all buttons get opened because they have all the same cached template id, however I want only the popover of the hoverd button to be opened.